# jquery/ajax not navigating to page 2 once page 1 is open

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery code below which is displayed in the `editsessionadmin.php` page. Now what is suppose to happen is that when this page is opened, in will perform the jquery/ajax function so that it navigates to the `module.php` page in order to be able to select a list of modules from a query, display each module as an option and display those options in the module drop down menu in the `editsessionadmin.php` page.

The problem I have is that it is not doing this. The jquery/ajax is not doing anything as that the Module drop down menu in the `editsessionadmin.php` script does not contain any options except for the `Please Select` option.

Does anybody know how to fix the jquery/ajax code in order to perform what I want it to perform?

Below is the `editsessionadmin.php` code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready( function(){
            function getModules() { 
            jQuery.ajax({ 
            type: "post", 
            url:  "module.php", 
            success: function(response){ 
            jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
            } 
            }); 
    });
            }
            </script>


....

<?php

    $moduleHTML = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 


?>
```

module.php page:

`

```
     // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

$moduleactive = 1;

$sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 


 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName);


$moduleHTML  = "";  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
     $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
} 


echo $moduleHTML; 

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 


?>`
```

Comment: We'll need more information in order to help you. What can you see in Firebug once you load editsessionadmin.php? Any error? Is the HTTP POST performed, how does the HTTP response look like?

Comment: @Gabriel In firebug if I go on .NET tab, it shows I only have 1 request which is $GET editsessionadmin. There are no errors being shown

Comment: It means the Ajax call is not fired, I think Kazetsukai nailed it in his answer: you're defining getModules() but never calling it.

Comment: upvoted comment coz you helped as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like it is creating a function on document ready, but never calling it. Also it looks like you have your brackets a little out of order. This becomes a little more obvious by indenting the code.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    function getModules() { 
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            type: "post", 
            url:  "module.php", 
            success: function(response){ 
                jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
            } 
        }); 
});
    } <--- This should be swapped with the line above
```

What you could do is delete the line `function getModules() {` and the spare `}` at the end, and then it should work or at least give you another GET in FireBug.